# square on the top of a square

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]
[image]
[image]

i am stuck with a question of mensuration for three days and i posted it on facebook and asked friends but no correct solution yet. 
please help .

Comment: answer is 125.44

Comment: How far have you gotten? Did you , for example, manage to determine $PQ$ at least?

Comment: Please show us your own attempts.

Comment: Please show us how far you've come with your own attempts; MSE is not "Do-My-Homework Central".

Comment: @MundronSchmidt  i have added an image of  my approach

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes. that is radius multiplied by square root of 2

Comment: i am having difficulty in determining the area of small region between the square and the circle

Comment: The length of the side of the small square is immediate from Pythagorean theorem. How come you didn't try it?

Comment: @Ennar thanks. can u tell me how to find the area of the small region between the circle and the smaller square?

Comment: I could, but why?

Answer (score 2):

$(14+a)^2 + (a/2)^2=(14*2^{0.5})^2
$
From geometry...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1037138)

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, yes it does provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must have $|XY|=2\cdot(|WX|/2)$, which is

$(\sin(v)-\sin(45))\cdot14\cdot\sqrt{2} = 2\cos(v)\cdot14\cdot\sqrt{2}$

Which you can solve for $v$ and substitute back into $|XY|$. Then the area is $4|XY|^2$.

Comment: which angle is v here ?

Comment: @VindhyachalVindhyachal Angle of OX relative to x-axis

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use symmetry and the Pythagoren Theorem for $\triangle AOT$, where $O$ is the center of the circle and $T$ is the intersection between $AB$ and the line through $O$ perpendicular to $AB$.

This directly gives you everything you need